MPLAB 8 and MPLAB X Checksums
I have a project that was built in MPLAB 8 using the Hi Tech C compiler. When I load it into MPLAB 8 to program a device I get a checksum (I use Unprotected checksum), then when I load it into MPLAB X IPE I get a completely different checksum. Is there a reason for this? Is there anyway to prove that both of these checksums are from the same file?
One thing I have notices is that the first 4 digits of the ID Memory in MPLAB 8 match up with the CP=OFF Checksum in MPLAB X IPE. Is this good enough to prove that the file is the same?
I hope this makes sense - any help is appreciated

There are many things that affect the checksum value generated by IDE.
Any MPLAB project that builds a C language project with more than one source code (.C) file will have a checksum that depends on the order that the (.obj) object files are linked.
Microchip has also changed the method that the IDE uses to create the checksum for many controllers since the release of MPLAB 8.92.
So if you are using the same version of C compiler with both the MPLAB and MPLABX tools this "should" produce the same (.HEX) file if and only if the object files are linked in the same order and yet the checksum can differ.
Use an ASCII text file compare tool, like one that comes with the windows shell (FC.EXE) to see how much the .HEX files have changed.
The only differences you should see are in the HEX file records used to program the IDLOCS in the target controller.
I suspect that I answered more question than you asked.
Another check you can try is to program a controller with the MPLABX IPE, then read it back with the MPLAB 8 IDE, save that as a HEX file, the reload that HEX file with the MPLAB 8 IDE and see what checksum it computes.
